# Target container is not a DOM element : MERN

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, mern

This is a part of my project. I want to create a Web Application with a stock dashboard.

I had a little issue with my code : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa31r.png)

I want to display a login form on my browser. I use React.js , Node.js & Npm. I wrote this index.js like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './client/App';
import NotFound from './client/NotFound';

import Home from './Home';

import HelloWorld from './client/HelloWorld';

import './client/styles.scss';


ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/helloworld" component={HelloWorld}/>
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </Router>)
, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Then, I wrote also this index.html file like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title> Web Application </title>

  <!-- link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/img/logo.png" -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script type="javascript" src="index.js"> </script>
</html>
```

Comment: did my answer make sense/ fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a **typo**: you have *too many parentheses* within your `render()` call. Perhaps you were trying to wrap your `JSX` within parentheses? However, `ReactDOM.render()` expects the first argument to be the element you wish to render (in your case just the **JSX**)  and the second argument to be the DOM element where this rendering should take place.

Maybe you could change your `render()` method to the following and seeing if this resolves your issue:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/helloworld" component={HelloWorld}/>
            <Route component={NotFound}/>
          </Switch>
       </App>
   </Router>, 
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Nope ! I don't really understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: replace your ReactDOM.render() method with the one I pasted in my answer.